# Ruby on Rails detecting a user, but still returning an error that it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, inspect

pretty new to RoR, but I'm using it to build a simple app and I'm running into an issue.

Basically my app uses three models: User, Post, and Thought. Where a User is a user, a Post is a post a user may make, and a Thought is like a comment on a Post.

I'm trying to get a post's thoughts to display below the post. On the post's `show.html.erb` page I have a call for `<%= render @thoughts %>`, which produces the `_thought.html.erb` template for each thought. The template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <li>
        <%= link_to thought.user.username, thought.user %>
        <span class="content"><%= thought.content %></span>
        <span class="timestamp"> Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(thought.created_at) %> ago.       </span>
    </li>
</div>
```

This previously worked, but now I added a form at the bottom and changed the ThoughtsController's create action a little bit. Now when I try to visit the post path I get this error: `<%= link_to thought.user.username, thought.user %> - undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass`. I get this error even when I change the view to simply display the username, like such: `<%= thought.user.username %>`

I thought, fair enough, there's something wrong and the thoughts are probably not getting connected to a User anymore. When I tried to test that out, something weird happened. I changed the thought view to simply display "`thought.inspect()`". The page then loaded fine, and the first thought was displayed like this:

```
<Thought id: 55, content: "Tenetur ut et sit nulla nesciunt modi eos.",
post_id: 295, user_id: 40, penny: false, created_at: "2013-08-26 21:37:55",
updated_at: "2013-08-26 21:37:55">
```

I thought, "hmm, this is weird. It seems to have a user_id. Maybe it's not connecting to the User itself. So I changed the post template to print out `thought.user.inspect()`. Now the first thought returns this:

```
#<User id: 40, username: "example_user39", created_at: "2013-08-26 21:37:41",
updated_at: "2013-08-26 21:37:41", password_digest:
"$2a$10$7urQB56QdkdXdNedsMe/KuENUTsQ.nk9FjKgLcE98sW6...",
remember_token: "336856d5e046b96983848f39d9e450aaa496252d", admin: false>
```

So I'm confused. When I try to print `thought.user.username` I get an error saying the Thought doesn't even have a User, but when I inspect them, I find out that the thought has a user and the user has a username. Am I missing something? What could be causing this? Where should I look? I can provide more info if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here's the server output:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <div>
    2:  <li>
    3:          <%= link_to thought.user.username, thought.user %>
    4:          <span class="content"><%= thought.content %></span>
    5:          <span class="timestamp"> Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(thought.created_at) %> ago. </span>
    6:  </li>
  app/views/thoughts/_thought.html.erb:3:in '_app_views_thoughts__thought_html_erb___991787178796439758_70190024095460'
  app/views/posts/show.html.erb:10:in '_app_views_posts_show_html_erb__1664758191839643789_70190022800060'
```

Here's my Thought.rb:

```
class Thought < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :post_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

Comment: Can you show the server output during this?

Comment: I'd like to see your `belongs_to :user` association on `Thought`

Comment: I added both of those in an edit.

Comment: Is it possible you have a `Thought` with `:user_id` having a `nil` value?

Comment: Wait, yes. I just checked and it seems like the last `Thought` in each `Post` has all properties as `nil`. Let me try to figure out why that's happening. It's weird because I'm getting the same error in my rspec tests and my rails server, even though I'm using FactoryGirl in one and db:populate with faker in another... Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, but that is absolutely why you're getting the `NilClass` error.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: I think I isolated the problem. The problematic line seems to be `@thought = @post.thoughts.build if signed_in?` in the `PostsController`'s `show` action. The `nil` Thought disappears when I remove it, but removing it also breaks the thought creation form because then the `form_for(@thought)` call returns a no parameters error. Any way around this?

Comment: would `@thought = Thought.new(:post_id => @post.id)` work?

Comment: Amend your question to include how the @thought is created with `.build` as you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you build your *thought* for form in way like this:

```
@new_thought = @post.thoughts.build
```

After that, @post.thoughts includes @new_thought, too. And @new_thought.user is nil.
That's why you get 500 error. You can modify your view:

```
<%- if thought.persisted? ->
 -- your code
<%- end -%
```